# MPMoviePlayerViewController slider jumps back

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` with local file.
Dragging time slider when playback status is **playing** works fine, but dragging it when playback status is **paused** make it jumps few seconds back from the time I dragged to.

Any property to set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's because of how movies are encoded.
Frames in a movie are encoded as the difference between the previous frame, so that only patches are saved in the movie.
Every now and then, a keyframe its inserted in the movie: a keyframe is a frame that's fully encoded.

You see it jumping back because it's going to the nearest *previous* keyframe.

Comment: Any idea which encoding is the most appropriate for my need? I have some stop point with accuracy of milliseconds (i.e stop the movie exactly at 00:05:16 (fifth sec...)

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Well, actually it is not just the keyframe (i-frame) frequency but also the chunk size (transport stream segments). @OhadIsraeli use a very high i-frame rate and a very short TS segment size to get as close as possible to your demands. Especially the extended i-frame rate will reduce the efficiency of your encoding.